# illustrator cs3- can't open newer ai file with multiple pages

Tags: adobe-illustrator, cs3

I am trying to open an illustrator file in ai cs3. The file was created in a newer version of illustrator and is comprised of 2 pages. when i open the file in cs3, i only get page #1.

how can i extract the second page?

Answer (score 0):

Adobe have made crucial changes in Illusrator CS4 as it can contain multiple(up to 99) artboards in one file. But CS3 opens one artboard at a time.

So, either you can install newer version or open CS4 file with CS4 installed machine and convert it to CS3.

Hope this works. :)